# Bootstrap - Pintar uma linha toda e menos uma coluna específica

Tags: jquery, table, bootstrap-4

O código acima quase funciona, só não pode pintar na primeira coluna, como posso resolver isso ?

```js
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('table-info')) {
        $(this).removeClass('table-info');
    }
    else {
    $('tr.table-info').removeClass('table-info');
        $(this).addClass('table-info');
    }
});
```

```css
.container-table {
  display: table;
}

.container-table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.container-table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-table">
  <div class="container-table-row">
    <div class="container-table-cell">
      <table class="table table-responsive">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Primeira coluna</th>
            <th>Segunda coluna</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode selecionar todas a `td` da *primeira coluna* (que no caso, é a segunda da tabela) e definir um `background` no CSS. Desta forma a classe incluída no jQuery não irá afetar a coluna.

Insira no CSS:

```
.table tr td:nth-child(2){
  background: white;
}
```

> Se for a primeira coluna **de fato** da tabela, basta alterar o
>   `.table tr td:nth-child(2){` para `.table th{`.

**[Veja no JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/736s3kxa/6/)**